# How to change a section background when clicking on a child element (ul li)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm setting up a tabbed section on my Wordpress site and one of the functions I'm trying to accomplish is changing the section background based on each specific tab clicked.

I've looked into some JS to see how I can accomplish this, but not sure if I'm headed the right direction.

Here is an image of the code:
[Section Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7X5k.jpg)

The highlighted section element is where the background-image is. I'm trying to change the background image of this section for each tab (li elements) selected.

Also, I can't add any specific classes or id to the li elements from the elementor backend. I believe if a specific class or id is necessary, it would have to be done via js.

Any insight will be helpful, thank you!

Edit:

First time posting on here, was advised to provide reproducible examples.

I have something basic I set up on JSFiddle that resembles the code I have currently set up. The only difference is instead of an image, I used the background color "red."

Essentially how can I change this background-color (or image) each time one of these li elements is clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/mkgdirect/mrwgnLvh/1/

```
<section class="tabbed-section">
  <ul class="tabbed-list">
    <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>



.tabbed-section {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You might try having a reproducible example. Posting an image of a blob of code won't be very effective on this platform (or anywhere I know in any case).

Comment: @ITgoldman Thank you! Do you have any idea of how to write this piece of code out? I've had a very rough idea of how it should work, but each time I tried to google how to set up the code, I couldn't understand which was the proper way or even correct or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Using js you can easily bind the click event to the li elements then find the closest `<section>` which you will set it's `style.backgroundImage` to be 'address-of-image.jpg'.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector("#my-section")
parent.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(function(li) {
  li.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var url = li.getAttribute('data-background-source');
    parent.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + url + ')';
  })
})
```

```css
section {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200);
}

li {
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="my-section">
  <ul>
    <li data-background-source="https://picsum.photos/id/200/200">
      click me
    </li>

    <li data-background-source="https://picsum.photos/id/201/200">
      click me
    </li>


    <li data-background-source="https://picsum.photos/id/203/200">
      click me
    </li>

  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I really appreciate your insight!

Quick Edit: Is there a way we can change this to have each li be unique? So each li has a specific image it shows and not changing each time?